# Retrofit Android : How To Get JSON Data With Retrofit MVP

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java, mvp, android-mvp

Please Guys I'm confused about how to retrieve data using retrofit with MVP architecture, I already try other steps but not worked for me, can you help me? I'm still learning to use retrofit with MVP architecture

Here's my JSON data :`

```
{
"status": 200,
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "token": {
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "expires_in": 1296000,
      "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5MmU4YWVmMC1jMzMzLTQxYjItODNlOC1lMGU4NTRmMWZhNDIiLCJqdGkiOiJmZDdiM2ViMTI1NWMxNzdkYTQ3MjMxNGQ5MDk0MzFhMGE2MmQzZDY3MTZhNmMyMzI0MGY1YmE4ZDAzYzI4NDJiZmE5ZDJhNzdlYTE3NDA4YyIsImlhdCI6MTYxOTA2MTk4NC44Nzc1NzksIm5iZiI6MTYxOTA2MTk4NC44Nzc1ODIsImV4cCI6MTYyMDM1Nzk4NC44NTA2NzMsInN1YiI6IjI4Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.K3QWMKTB3XPz8YGAfizKkeaB6JySjnT5hS4o_sKt11-VxX7S45IN39TJeqaxCeytuy_23rerfyTI_8KF4J3GulStOy3vnfgZ-l5G653bLJH2m46PYgjhHQlxy9cdbhV8HG7eO9A4-MwbKYQsv8teo1lupd3dQ4gEgwEme-SbMgxtMWJMPOubqLWAQlHsjOyPNgB1v_OEgtqs6ZmZdi5BkHNHiiPoTtBeeXof_bE4l45IkET3nAlujomu1kXEXe_LSIYQooPUa34eobJzHPzpfgomvykK--SsrI5A1-8phG16qUVhbROUM3dqwFuIJN4vR1vGKgl_xpUk8z8Gh_ABsURxJLK2JhIG5mYYovx7NyrkyDBEUb3NCt_85yB0hUIbKaKIZ1xY_s694ZjSZNoYsqtPPyGm0nreU2qUBbS5Tf1XOdyfT5sHR9e0bhkZIuW9lNTg64zpC9hCkTmggHLmQ8j25HlgpaBfAZrQnkZTqVt2LRcF-vAi1O9DvND2hD6OC09NBH7oBS_hElEMvBWjdpos4Q1Ij21uxFXEDmFttyxBnYAA_uKZ7GQMXAWc6wfWCMVKeGayJinLLRic5B1fX-iotsrKjr1LSLiPUF9d7RhCu-pZekvYmzAKvFF16_yWJnCLQZ0zxjM0zLrHZk336gpLnNf4ifw-K8OmN6kh838",
      "refresh_token": "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"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "xxxx",
      "email": "xxxx",
      "email_verified_at": "2021-03-15T10:20:46.000000Z",
      "current_team_id": 28,
      "created_at": "2021-03-15T10:19:38.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-15T10:20:46.000000Z",
      "deleted_at": null,
      "current_team": {
        "id": 28,
        "owner_id": 28,
        "name": "xxx",
        "logo": "team/logos/zlxKwZmrmkwd6b9nisQMAsNIS32UQfOqo2u2d4FW.png",
        "address": "Jl...",
        "callback_url": "https://callback.ppndev.xyz",
        "bank_id": "1",
        "account_number": "23312312",
        "status": "verified",
        "created_at": "2021-03-15T10:19:38.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-03-29T02:11:48.000000Z",
        "meta": null
      }
    },
    "team": {
      "id": 28,
      "owner_id": 28,
      "name": "xxx",
      "logo": "team/logos/zlxKwZmrmkwd6b9nisQMAsNIS32UQfOqo2u2d4FW.png",
      "address": "Jl...",
      "callback_url": "https://callback.ppndev.xyz",
      "bank_id": "1",
      "account_number": "23312312",
      "status": "verified",
      "created_at": "2021-03-15T10:19:38.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-29T02:11:48.000000Z",
      "meta": null
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my response :

```
public class Connector implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private String success;

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Data> data;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public List<Data> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Connector{" +
            "status='" + status + '\'' +
            ", success='" + success + '\'' +
            ", data=" + data +
            '}';
}
```

My view interfaces :

```
    public interface DataView {
    void onConnected(Connector response);
    void onErrorResponse(String errorResponse);
}
```

My PresenterImpl :

```
    public interface DataPresenterImpl {
    void connected(String status, String success, Connector connector);
}
```

My Presenter :

```
    public class DataPresenter implements DataPresenterImpl {

    DataView view;
    Context context;

    public DataPresenter(Context context, DataView view) {
        this.view = view;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void connected(String status, String success, Connector connector) {
        final Observable<Connector> connectorApi = NetworkClient.getNetworkClient(context)
                .getConnector().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        DisposableObserver<Connector> con =  connectorApi.subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Connector>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Connector connector) {
                view.onConnected(connector);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                view.onErrorResponse(e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My NetworkClient :

```
public class NetworkClient extends Application {

    public static NetworkAPI getNetworkClient(Context context){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().setLenient().create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(getClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).build();

        return retrofit.create(NetworkAPI.class);
    }

    public static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addInterceptor(getLoggingInterceptor())
                .build();
    }


    public static HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level getInterceptorLevel(){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            return HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY;
        else
            return HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE;
    }

    public static HttpLoggingInterceptor getLoggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(getInterceptorLevel());
        return httpLoggingInterceptor;
    }
}
```

My API interfaces :

```
public interface NetworkAPI {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("xxxx")
    Observable<LoginResponse> login(@Field("username") String username,
                                    @Field("password") String password,
                                    @Field("serial_number") String serial_number);

    @GET("xxx")
    Observable<Connector> getConnector();

}
```

Comment: Can you pls share the issue that you are facing with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

You are parsing the key `data` into the list but it is a `JSONObject` containing child objects: `token`, `user`, and `team`.

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Data> data;
```

This code is expecting JSONArray but your response has JSONObject.

**Solution:**

First, create POJO classes for each object for the child objects inside the `data` key. Declare the variable for these classes inside the `Data` class for serialization. Finally, change the above declaration `private List<Data> data` to `private Data data`,